# How to call serializeArray on query string

Tags: jquery, serialization

Is there any way to call serializeArray() on query string?

```
str = "utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=tzI2FU1g7SA8kZ94Nk0ykZ4nL6Kbp%2Fq8dg5%2BdEinpTnifta%2BWEu3ZzFkc3p5rUfQTQfJI8Q%3D%3D&entity_type=non-npe&caction=ABCD&aa_center=1100+-+Cossasations&numbers=&pat_numbers="
```

I tried $.param(str).serializeArray()  but it didn't work for me. Is there any inbuilt method for it.

Comment: Please show the code you tried and didn't work, string variable is already serialized, do you mean to unserialize it?

Comment: @ROOT I just want to call serializeArray() on the above string.

Comment: @ROOT In the documentation https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/, it is specifically mentioned you can only call on form objects

Comment: do you mean to add/concatenate array of values to the query string?

Answer (score 1):

There is no use in calling serializeArray on a string

Perhaps you meant something like this?

```js
const parms = new URLSearchParams("utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=tzI2FU1g7SA8kZ94Nk0ykZ4nL6Kbp%2Fq8dg5%2BdEinpTnifta%2BWEu3ZzFkc3p5rUfQTQfJI8Q%3D%3D&entity_type=non-npe&caction=ABCD&aa_center=1100+-+Cossasations&numbers=&pat_numbers=")

// it is now an array of key/value
  
parms.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key,":",value || "empty"));
```